# Adding users to a custom group in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = true;
//$wgGroupPermissions['Human Resource'] = $wgGroupPermissions['user'];
//$wgGroupPermissions['Human Resources']['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['Human Resource']['edit'] = true;
//$wgGroupPermissions['Human Resources']['protect'] = true; // 1.5.0
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgWhitelistRead = array( "Main Page", "Special:Userlogin", "-", "MediaWiki:Monobook.css" );
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

I have added a group, but in my special pages i cannot add a user to this group in MediaWiki

Comment: What version of MediaWiki? Please show us all the relevant lines from LocalSettings.php.

Comment: Bah, ignore comment about the version; I'm tired. What happens when you go to Special:Userrights? Does the group appear in the list of available groups?

Comment: Yes it appears in the group list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the [Special:UserRights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights) page to change user's groups. To be able to go to that page you need to be in a group with the 'userrights' right. By default, only the [bureaucrat group](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Assigning_permissions) has that right.

You can check what groups you are a member of in Special:ListUsers and check what rights those groups have in Special:ListGroupRights

Comment: I am with all rights as u mentioned, the group is visible but when i select a user and check the group its not adding to the user

Comment: Are you able to add users to the predefined groups, ie. Sysop or Bots?

Comment: how to add a single user to a group?

Answer (score 3):

I see that your custom user group's name, "Human Resources," contains a space.

I recently had the exact same problem and it turned out that the user rights page chokes if you try to add a user to a group whose name contains a space. Calling the group, say, "HumanResources" should fix the problem. This is a new development, as older versions of Mediawiki supported user groups with spaces without any problems.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply! I would have never guessed